# jasmine unit testing - testing for an undefined property of an object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, undefined, jasmine

I have the following statement

```
expect(A.["BAR"].name).toEqual("foo");
```

which due to the fact my object A has the top level property "BAR" and bar has the value "foo" passes.

I'd like to test my structure to confirm a property "NONEXISTINGPROP" has not be defined.
e.g.

```
expect(A.["NONEXISTINGPROP"].name).not.toBeDefined();
```

However I seem to get

```
  "TypeError: A.[NONEXISTINGPROP] is undefined"
```

in the jasmine test runner this is exactly what I want to confirm. Any idea why Jasmine is crying. I was hoping for it to pass this.

Thanks SO

Comment: Cant seem to answer this question directly but the answer seems to be ...   expect(A.["NONEXISTINGPROP"]).not.toBeDefined();  ie remove the name bit

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The answer seems to be ...

```
expect(A.NONEXISTINGPROP).not.toBeDefined();
```

ie remove the name bit

Comment: You don't need the `.`

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up, Jasmine has had `toBeUndefined` since v1.3.0 (see [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/matchers.html#toBeUndefined)).

```
expect(A.NONEXISTINGPROP).toBeUndefined();
```