# AngularJS controller unit test using the "controller as" syntax

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm having some trouble adapting [this test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836751/385846) to use the "controller as" syntax. Here's what I have ...

The controller I'm testing is:

```
function MyCtrl ($scope, someService) {
  someService.get()
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.person = data;
  });
 }
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

The unit test is:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var scope,
    fakeService, 
    controller, 
    q, 
    deferred;

  beforeEach(function () {
      fakeService = {
          get: function () {
              deferred = q.defer();
              deferred.resolve({ "test": "data" });
              return deferred.promise;
          }
        };
      spyOn(fakeService, 'get').and.callThrough();
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $q, $rootScope) {
      q = $q;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $controller('MyCtrl as person', { $scope: scope, someService: fakeService });
  }));

  it('The person object is not defined yet', function () {
      expect(scope.person).not.toBeDefined();
  });
```

This test for `scope.person` fails with the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648303/jasmine-unit-testing-testing-for-an-undefined-property-of-an-object) where I've changed `expect(scope.person)` to `expect(scope)`, but that returns `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.22, Karma 0.12.21 and 0.2.2 of the karma-jamsine plugin.

Thanks in advance for whatever suggestions you have.

Comment: fakePwsService != fakeService

Comment: edited to fix the fakePwsService != fakeService typo

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `fakePwsService != fakeService` that @JBNizet pointed out.

The promise that is created by `$q.defer()` doesn't have the `success()` method.

The `.success()` and `.error()` methods are special ones that added by `$http` service itself.

Therefore, if you would like to mock the `someService` this way, you have to also mimic the `.success()` yourself as well.

```
fakePwsService = {
  get: function () {
    deferred = q.defer();
    deferred.resolve({ "test": "data" });

    var promise = deferred.promise;

    promise.success = function(fn) {
      promise.then(function(response) {
        fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
      });
      return promise;
    };

    promise.error = function(fn) {
      promise.then(null, function(response) {
        fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
      });
      return promise;
    };

    return promise;
  }
};
```

The above code copied from [http.js#L743](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ng/http.js#L743).

PS. This problem isn't related to "controller as" syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the note re: the "controller as" syntax.

Comment: This answer works if I change `$controller('PwsCtrl as person', { $scope: scope, pwsService: fakePwsService })` to `$controller('PwsCtrl', { $scope: scope, pwsService: fakePwsService })`. Is it possible to run this test using the "as" syntax?

Comment: Is there any error? May be it because your assert statement is incorrectly, it should be `expect(scope.person).toBeDefined();`. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/01fvz43nodMlzEmgEIro?p=preview).